# JavaScript Firebase: Query Snapshot Always Null

Tags: javascript, firebase

No matter what I do I can't seem to figure out a way to access the child "onSite", which shows as being there when I log snapshot.val(), but I cannot figure out how to access it.

Code:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('facebook_id').equalTo(fbID).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    console.log(snapshot.child("onSite").val());
});
```

Here is the response:
[image]

It shouldn't be null, it should be false. I can't do child("4mUUjF...").child("onSite").val() because I don't know what the ID is before the query. Using an each loop doesn't work, it only loops through the first level, which is the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle the list, by using `Snapshot.forEach()`:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('facebook_id').equalTo(fbID)
.once("value").then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.child("onSite").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the answer I saw before, and it didn't work for me. Now I tried it and it works like it's supposed to... Go figure. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

## Use the key of the object

Get the snapshot val and then find the key with the `Object.keys` method. This will allow you to then get inside the snap. Once there it's a simple matter of accessing the values like any other object.

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('facebook_id').equalTo(fbID).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    let snap = snapshot.val();
    let key = Object.keys(snap)[0]
    console.log(snap[key].onSite);
})
```